# Xpath with a fragment and src- How can i get Information from behind a "fragment/src"?

Tags: xml, xpath

i dont know how to get information behind src. Maybe someone can help me to find my mistake and maybe discribe why my tries are not working.

Code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fragment src="https://www.youtube.com/...">
</fragment>`

What i want to get from code: 
https://www.youtube.com/...

My XPath tries:

```
//@src
--or--
//fragment/@src
--or--
//fragment[@src='*']/@src
```

What i get:
Nothin

Thx for help
Greetings Dirac

Comment: if sputnick's answer solved the problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
string(//fragment/@src)
```